# cannot resolve symbol Network android studio

Tags: java, android

I am running android project. But I am getting the following error:

```
/home/sultan/StudioProjects/android-client/app/src/main/java/edu/cmu/cs/gabriel/network/ResultReceivingThread.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
import android.net.Network;
                  ^
  symbol:   class Network
  location: package android.net
Note: /home/sultan/StudioProjects/android-client/app/src/main/java/edu/cmu/cs/gabriel/CameraPreview.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
1 error
```

The error is in this line:

```
import android.net.Network
```

I don't understand how to resolve this error. Please help me.

Comment: The class exists and is not deprecated (and not removed). This should not happen

Comment: Make sure that your imports appear after your package declaration, but before your class definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your target SDK version less than 21 in your build.gradle file?

`android.net.Network` was added in API label 21.